# Finite element method books

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, finite-element-method

I know this question has been asked before; I just want to enquire if anybody has any suggestions to learn how to compute finite element problems, including plenty of examples.

The topics I would like to focus in are as follows:

Introduction to finite elements for 1D and 2D problems covering:

- weak formulation
- Galerkin approximation
- Shape functions
- Isoparametric elements

Key examples with walkthrough of common problems such as:

- Applying to heat equation
- Applying to beam equation
- Eigenvalue Problems
- Nonlinear Problems

Any recommendations would be sincerely appreciated (and happy new year!)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Larson–Bengzon - The Finite Element Method: Theory, Implementation and Applications](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642332869). It contains everything you requested for. They use Matlab as a programming environment.

Comment: (+1), Nice book, do you have any other recommendations too?

Answer (score 0):

A good introductory book is "Understanding and implementing the finite element method" from Mark S. Gockenbach. Some of your listed examples are covered by implementations of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the book *Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations by the Finite Element Method* by Claes Johnson. I think, it chooses the right level of abstraction for a first book on this topic.